# Can't flash CM0+ Core in NUCLEO STM32WL

Tags: stm32, cortex-m, flash-memory

In a wireless project, I'm using en Nucleo STM32WLJC1 in dual core configuration. 
I take DualCore Ping Pong ST code example, that I rework to make my own application.
I didn't touch anything of the CMO+ project, I only work on the applicative layer in CM4.

I've some problems about flashing the CM0+ Core. 
The first time I flashed the board it works and now I've most of the times the folowing error when I try to flash the CM0+. It sometimes work one time for no reason.

**Pop-up Problem Occurred Windows :**

```
 Error in final launch sequence:
 Failed to start GDB server Failed to start GDB server Error in
 initializing ST-LINK device. Reason: (255) Unknown. Please check power
 and cabling to target.
```

**Console informations**

```
STMicroelectronics ST-LINK GDB server. Version 6.0.0 Copyright (c)
2021, STMicroelectronics. All rights reserved.
Starting server with the following options:
Persistent Mode            : Disabled
Logging Level              : 1
Listen Port Number         : 61234
Status Refresh Delay       : 15s
Verbose Mode               : Disabled
SWD Debug                  : Enabled
 
Target unknown error 32

Error in initializing ST-LINK device. Reason: Unknown. Please check
power and cabling to target.
```

It looks like the STlink can't reach the core...

- Someone may know what is happening ?
- Is there a flashing configuration that has to be done? (to chose which core we want to flash)

Comment: Maybe also ask at: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ (you can use this same SO account to post there).

Comment: You could also ask directly at [ST communiy](https://community.st.com/s/). There is a similar [question](https://community.st.com/s/question/0D53W00000UfnbgSAB/the-interface-firmware-failed-to-resethalt-the-target-mcu) about error `32`. Because sometimes it works, you could also try to update the ST-Link firmware on the Nucleo. Maybe it's a timing issue in the firmware.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I tried to use STM32Cube Programmer and thanks to it I am able to access the memory. So with that I succed to flash the CM0+ only if I erase the memory before... Just after flashing the CM0+ I have a warning saying that the core memory is now locked. It happear to be the source of my problem but I don't know how to unlock it... The Options Byte of read out protection is set to AA (no protection). Still investigating !

Comment: Hello, the solution has been find on ST Community  just  [here](https://community.st.com/s/question/0D53W00001BR0iKSAT/i-cant-run-or-debug-my-cm0-with-nucleowl55jc1)